# pusher subscribe to event sometimes only

Tags: javascript, websocket

why pusher works randomly , sometimes it can receive the push , sometimes it is not ...

it is working only when the debugger show subscribed

```
Connection  1614.1447055    Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000   06:23:34
Subscribed  1614.1447055    Channel: export 06:23:34
```

but when debugger show

```
Connection  1624.1445840    Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

but no subscribed , it is not working.
Why? It is the same javascript.

and it is taking really long for it to subscribe , why?

```
<head>
    <title>Share Your Application</title>
<script src="http://js.pusherapp.com/1.9/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
      if (window.console && window.console.log) window.console.log(message);
    };
    // Flash fallback logging - don't include this in production
    WEB_SOCKET_DEBUG = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('ba6867c72bd360e49f8c');


    var channel = pusher.subscribe('export');

    channel.bind("project-2.html", function(d) {
        alertBox_Show("Export successful!","Thank you for exporting the site. Please check your download folder.");
        window.location = d.link;
        sessionStorage["is_export"] = true;
        unlockScreen(); 
        $("#ajax_loading_image").hide();
        $( "#republish_confirmation" ).dialog( "close" );
    });

    channel.bind("project-2.iads", function(d) {
        alertBox_Show("Export successful!","Thank you for exporting the site. Please check your download folder.");
        window.location = d.link;
        sessionStorage["is_export"] = true;
        unlockScreen(); 
        $("#ajax_loading_image").hide();
        $( "#republish_confirmation" ).dialog( "close" );
    });

    channel.bind("my_event", function(d) {
        alert(d);
    });

</script>

</head>
```

Comment: i think i should use pubnub ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... i found the reason why. The pusher.connection.state; is connecting. It is taking really long time to connect in chrome linux ....